# Как указать потокам работать по очереди в цикле

Tags: java, многопоточность, циклы

У меня есть такие потоки. **Factory** производит детали(10 в день), а **Factions** их забирает(рандомно 5 штук в день). По моей задаче сначала отрабатывает **Factory**, потом **Factions**, потом снова **Factory** и так по кругу(число итераций может быть любое).  Вот только я не понимаю, где именно надо это прописывать. В потоках ли это прописывать или в классах, которые вызывают эти потоки... Если что то непонятно объяснил, извиняюсь, так как сам в ступоре.

```
public class FactionsThread implements Runnable {
    private final int DAYS = 10;
    private final Factions factions;

    public FactionsThread(Factions factions) {
        this.factions = factions;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        factions.getPartsFromFactory(); //вызывает метод из класса Factions, который забирает детали из Factory;
        factions.printAmountsPart();
    }
}
```

```
public class FactoryProduceThread implements Runnable {
    private final int DAYS = 10;
    private final Factory factory;

    public FactoryProduceThread(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start producing");
        factory.produceParts(); //вызывает метод из класса Factory, который производит детали.
        factory.printFactoryDayResult();
        System.out.println("End producing");
    }
```

```
public class Factory {
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private int head = 0;
    private int torso = 0;
    private int hand = 0;
    private int feet = 0;

    public void produceParts() {
        final int PARTS_EACH_DAY = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < PARTS_EACH_DAY; i ++) {
            switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
                case 0:
                    head++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    torso++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    hand++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    feet++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printFactoryDayResult() {
        System.out.println("---Factory producing day result---\n Heads: " + head
                + " Torso: " + torso
                + " Hands: " + hand
                + " Feet: " + feet);
    }

    public boolean pickUpHead() {
        if (head > 0) {
            head--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean pickUpTorso() {
        if (torso > 0) {
            torso--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean pickUpHand() {
        if (hand > 0) {
            hand--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean pickUpFeet() {
        if (feet > 0) {
            feet--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

```
public class Factions {
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Factory factory;
    private int head = 0;
    private int torso = 0;
    private int hand = 0;
    private int feet = 0;

    public Factions(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void getPartsFromFactory() {
        final int MAX_GETTING_PARTS_EACH_DAYS = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_GETTING_PARTS_EACH_DAYS; i++) {
            switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
                case 0:
                    if (factory.pickUpHead()) {
                        head++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (factory.pickUpTorso()) {
                        torso++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (factory.pickUpHand()) {
                        hand++;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (factory.pickUpFeet()) {
                        feet++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printAmountsPart() {
        System.out.println("---" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "---\n Amount heads: " + head
                + " Amount torso: " + torso
                + " Amount hands: " + hand
                + " Amount feet: " + feet);
    }
```

Comment: у вас ситуация , которая описывается как Consumer-Producer. вам не нужно пытаться синхронизировать потоки, потому как при такой синхронизации вы ничего не выиграете, а получите множество проблем: код усложнится, потребление ресурсов увеличится, в целом скорость выполнения упадет по сравнению с выполнением в 1 потоке. в большой разработке для таких целей используется Kafkaили подобные решения. в вашем случае будет достаточно взять потокобезопасную (скорее всего неблокирующую) очередь из пакета concurent.

Comment: Полагаю что нужно реализовать паттерн observer. Если обязательно нужно реализовать путем низкоуровневого создания и управления потоками, то как вариант можно использовать следующий алгоритм. Создать коллекцию ConcurrentLinkedDeque, в эту очередь Factory в цикле записывает новые детали в конец, а Factions в цикле забирает детали из начала очереди, проверяя заранее есть ли там что либо при каждом цикле. Но я бы конечно если есть возможность использовать сторонние библиотеки, взял бы RxJava, создал бы два Observable с указанием в каких потоках выполняться, а не создавать вручную весь механизм.

Comment: @Дмитрий я добавил больше кода для понимания. Идея в том, что фабрика сначала производит детали(10 штук), а только потом залетают потоки Faction и кто успел, тот и молодец. Очередь не подходит для меня, так как порядок забора деталей у меня случайный. Если все потоки запустить одновременно, то не факт что фабрика будет отрабатывать быстрее и, получается, Faction останутся ни с чем. Я с потоками познакомился неделю назад, так что много еще чего в них не понимаю. У меня сейчас не стоит задача оптимизации. Я пробовал использовать join и wait, но результата не дало.

Comment: Очередь никак не повлияет на случайность забора деталей. Во-вторых, очередь для такой задачи как раз и является простым и удобным способом синхронизации. Наверно вы не до конца понимаете, как она будет работать. В любом случае вам нужно как-то обрабатывать ситуацию, когда `Faction` хочет получить деталь, а ее пока нет. С очередью он просто будет ждать пока фабрика не добавит ее в очередь. Точно так же можно ограничить и фабрику, чтобы если `Faction` не справляются, то она подождала и не добавляла пока деталей в очередь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал код таким образом. Создал общий склад куда обращаются `Faction` и `Factory`. Создал в `Storage` переменную `isDay`, что бы указывать, когда поток должен засыпать. И при помощи `wait()` отправлял в сон потоки по очереди. Код не финальный, но идею реализовал.

```
public class Factions {
    private final Storage storage;
    private final String head = "head";
    private final String torso = "torso";
    private final String hand = "hand";
    private final String feet = "feet";
    private Map<String, Integer> partsList = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
            head, 0,
            torso, 0,
            hand, 0,
            feet, 0
    ));

    public Factions(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public void getPartsFromStorage() {
        partsList = storage.getPartsToFactions();
    }

    public void printAmountsPart() {
        System.out.println("---" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "---\n " + partsList.toString());
    }
}
```

```
public class Factory {
    Storage storage;

    public Factory(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    public synchronized void factoryStartWork() {
        storage.produceParts();
    }
}
```

```
public class Storage {
    public boolean isDay = true;
    Random random = new Random();
    private final String head = "head";
    private final String torso = "torso";
    private final String hand = "hand";
    private final String feet = "feet";
    private Map<String, Integer> partsList = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
            head, 0,
            torso, 0,
            hand, 0,
            feet, 0
    ));

    public synchronized void produceParts() {
        while (!isDay) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        final int PARTS_EACH_DAY = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < PARTS_EACH_DAY; i++) {
            switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
                case 0:
                    partsList.put(head, partsList.get(head) + 1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    partsList.put(torso, partsList.get(torso) + 1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    partsList.put(hand, partsList.get(hand) + 1);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    partsList.put(feet, partsList.get(feet) + 1);
                    break;
            }
        }
        setDay(false);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized Map<String, Integer> getPartsToFactions() {
        while (isDay) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Map<String, Integer> partsListForFactions = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
                head, 0,
                torso, 0,
                hand, 0,
                feet, 0
        ));
        final int PARTS_EACH_DAY = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < PARTS_EACH_DAY; i++) {
            switch (random.nextInt(4)) {
                case 0:
                    if (partsList.get(head) > 0) {
                        partsList.replace(head, partsList.get(head) - 1);
                        partsListForFactions.put(head, partsListForFactions.get(head) + 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (partsList.get(torso) > 0) {
                        partsList.replace(torso, partsList.get(torso) - 1);
                        partsListForFactions.put(torso, partsListForFactions.get(torso) + 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (partsList.get(hand) > 0) {
                        partsList.replace(hand, partsList.get(hand) - 1);
                        partsListForFactions.put(hand, partsListForFactions.get(hand) + 1);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (partsList.get(feet) > 0) {
                        partsList.replace(feet, partsList.get(feet) - 1);
                        partsListForFactions.put(feet, partsListForFactions.get(feet) + 1);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        setDay(true);
        notifyAll();
        return partsListForFactions;
    }

    public void printFactoryDayResult() {
        System.out.println("---Factory producing day result---\n " + partsList.toString());
    }

    public void setDay(boolean day) {
        isDay = day;
    }
}
```

```
public class FactionsThread implements Runnable {
    private final Factions factions;

    public FactionsThread(Factions factions) {
        this.factions = factions;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            factions.getPartsFromStorage();
            factions.printAmountsPart();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class FactoryProduceThread implements Runnable {
    private final Factory factory;
    private final Storage storage;

    public FactoryProduceThread(Factory factory, Storage storage) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            factory.factoryStartWork();
            storage.printFactoryDayResult();
        }
    }
}
```